# How to join a KStream to a KTable when key of the element of stream is held by the records in table

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

For an example, I have these classes

```
Order {String customerId, String orderId, List<Product> products}
Product {String id, String name, int quantity}
DeliveryNote {String id (orderId + productId + customerId), String orderId, int quantity}
```

Now, Order stream is processed like this

```
KStream<String, Order> orderStream = StreamBuilder.toStream("orders");

KTable<String, DeliveryNote> deliveryNoteTable =
    orderStream
        .mapValues((orderKey, order) -> order to List<DeliveryNote>)
        .flatMap(DeliveryNotes.stream())
        .selectKey(DeliveryNote::id)
        .groupByKey()
        .aggregate(DeiveryNote::new, (deliveryNoteId, existingNote, newNote) -> existingNote.apply(newNote));
```

now I need to join the orderStream with deliveryNoteTable and if there is no Product in the Order then I want to close all the existing DeliveryNotes for that order. Order object can't give me ids of all the associated deliveryNotes, however all the deliveryNote items in the right hand side table has their associated orderIds, if I can some how scan through the records of the table then I can close the records which are having matching orderId.

foreign Key Extractor will work when I start with the deliveryNote KTable and join a KTable of Orders.

Any help here will be much appreciated.

Comment: Overall, it sounds like a case for a custom processor? As you want to _modify_ the `deliveryNoteTable`, regular DSL operator like joins don't allow you to do this (because if join read from the table only). -- I am even wondering if the aggregation itself makes sense? It strips out a lot of information that you later re-add via the join? So why not just keep everything you need to begin with?

Comment: Thanks Matt. My actual use case if different which I can't reveal here. But main question here is - 'How to join a KStream to a KTable when key of the element of stream is held by the records in table'. I had to come up this Order/Delivery example to explain my problem. I need to join a record of stream with a collection of records from KTable. Record from Stream can't tell which items from Table it needs to join. These are the records in the KTable which keep the key of the record of the Stream.

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-955%3A+Add+stream-table+join+on+foreign+key is my requirement.

Comment: Atm, the only way would be to create a new join table: `joinTable = table.groupBy("joinElement").aggregate(/*Collect list of rows*/);`

Comment: And that aggregated list is going to stay as a single record in the KTable (and in state store and in Kafka as well). Which I don't want. Out of topic - would it be great if aggregated list can be stored as separate records in Kafka and can be assembled back as List on start up if we need to re-hydrate the state store. But in state store that can be kept as single store. What do you think?

Comment: Correct, that is what would happen, and I agree it's not ideal. Not sure if splitting the List into multiple records in the changelog topic would be possible -- I see a LOT of difficulties doing it. Maybe there are ways to solve those difficulties, but from top of my head I would rather say, most likely not possible to do.

Comment: For sure, it is not an easy problem to solve. let me give it a thought, I have few things in my mind. Will share those with you.